# `Invalid Qualifier` error on an Array variable with Combobox object names

Tags: excel, vba

I get an `Invalid Qualifier` error in the `Cbx_name(i).Clear` line. This code is placed in a separate module which i'll use: `Call Dynamic_cbx` on the UserForms events. I believe I referenced it right in the module by using the form `[UserForm Name].[Combo Box Name]`, but i'm not sure.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Dynamic_cbx()
Dim dCell As Range
Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary
Dim Cbx_count As Long, i As Long
Cbx_count = 8

ReDim Cbx_loop(1 To Cbx_count) As Long, Cbx_name(1 To Cbx_count) As Long

Cbx_loop(1) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Foil Profile").ListObjects("tblFoilProfile").ListColumns("SUPPLIER").Index
Cbx_loop(2) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Foil Profile").ListObjects("tblFoilProfile").ListColumns("FOIL DESCRIPTION").Index
Cbx_loop(3) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Foil Profile").ListObjects("tblFoilProfile").ListColumns("BRAND").Index
Cbx_loop(4) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Foil Profile").ListObjects("tblFoilProfile").ListColumns("COLOR NUMBER").Index
Cbx_loop(5) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Foil Profile").ListObjects("tblFoilProfile").ListColumns("FOIL WIDTH").Index
Cbx_loop(6) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Foil Profile").ListObjects("tblFoilProfile").ListColumns("UOM (Foil Width)").Index
Cbx_loop(7) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Foil Profile").ListObjects("tblFoilProfile").ListColumns("FOIL LENGTH").Index
Cbx_loop(8) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Foil Profile").ListObjects("tblFoilProfile").ListColumns("UOM (Foil Length)").Index

Cbx_name(1) = frmFoilPanel.cbxSupplier
Cbx_name(2) = frmFoilPanel.cbxFoilDescription
Cbx_name(3) = frmFoilPanel.cbxFoilBrand
Cbx_name(4) = frmFoilPanel.cbxColorNumber
Cbx_name(5) = frmFoilPanel.cbxFoilWidth
Cbx_name(6) = frmFoilPanel.cbxUOMfw
Cbx_name(7) = frmFoilPanel.cbxFoilLength
Cbx_name(8) = frmFoilPanel.cbxUOMfl

For i = 1 To Cbx_count
    Cbx_name(i).Clear
Next i

For i = 1 To Cbx_count
    With dict
        For Each dCell In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("List_Box").Range(Col_Letter(i) & "2:" & Col_Letter(i) & TotalRowsCount("Foil Purchases.xlsm", "List_Box", "tblFoilInfoHelper"))
            If Not .exists(dCell.Value) Then
                .Add dCell.Value
            End If
        Next dCell
        Cbx_name(i).List = .keys
        Set dict = Nothing
    End With
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an array. To empty the content at an index do

```
Cbx_name(i) = vbNullString
```

There is no .Clear method for an array index.

Comment: Oh right, but there is a `.Clear` method for comboboxes right? Does the `Cbx_name(i) = vbNullString` clear the contents of the combobox similarly to `cbx.Clear`? or does it just clear the array's space. I am quite confused how it works if I reference the combobox object to an array

Comment: No. It puts an empty string literal at that index position so replaces whatever is in that index with "". If you want to empty the entire cbx then call .Clear on that.

Comment: Didn't realize the blunder I made lol by thinking `.Clear` will clear the comboboxes when it's using an array. Thanks that means i'll have to declare 2 arrays one for clearing the comboboxes and one for referencing the combobox name. In my case is there a way to hit 2 in 1 like how I was planning to do it in the code?

Comment: Maybe if you have more than one combobox. You need the object to call the .Clear on

Comment: I know it's a little unrelated to the main question, but I also did the same mistake in the bottom of the code `Cbx_name(i).List = .keys`. So I changed `Cbx_name(1) = frmFoilPanel.cbxSupplier.List` so i'll just do `Cbx_name(i) = .keys` instead, but I get an error `Invalid use of Null`. Can you suggest in the answer the proper way of looping the way I intend it to be? If possible

Comment: What is the value of .keys?

Comment: It is a string in my case or `dcell.Value`

Comment: You need an array such that 



Worksheets("yourWorksheet").ComboBox1.List = yourArray. You have the object on the left and the assignment array on the right. .keys should produce an array.

Comment: I just realized I might need `AddItem` since i'm looping through 1 by 1. I think i'll try to debug the code first since. Thanks for the help

Comment: If you are looping yes. If you are assigning to the object in one go you can use an array as produced by .Keys

Comment: Oh right it's outside the loop and `.keys` returns an array. Thanks

Comment: The issue with assigning `Worksheets("yourWorksheet").ComboBox1.List = YourArray` is that i'll need to copy paste the last `For-Next` loop, `Cbx_count` number of times. I was wondering if there is a faster way

Comment: Can you pastebin your current code and share link here? It sounds like maybe a nestled loop might work but I am not sure without seeing.

Comment: This is the whole module actually not included is the userform but should not be all that relevant. The thing is for each combo box, the dictionary should reset. Actually I should ask another question for this perhaps on Code Review first with the long working version. Thanks for the help

Comment: Ok. I may pop by Code Review for a peek